# Sitecore Fast Query Gives Parse Exception

Tags: sitecore

Why am I getting this error with the code below `ParseException: End of string expected at position 4.`

Here's the code: The error is on the 3rd line.

```cs
var db = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");
string query = @"fast:/sitecore/content/foodservice/home/Products/3492-5326/3518-7";
Item item = db.SelectSingleItem(query);
return item;
```

Can we use a fast query with `SelectSingleItem()`? I was trying to avoid the `get folder contents and loop through each item until I find the target solution.` Suggestions?

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687405/escaping-reserved-words

Comment: Anyone know how to escape special characters used in text fields, such as an apostrophe in a content item description?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847831/sitecore-fast-query-how-to-search-for-text-containing-special-characters-such

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug when using Fast Query and SelectSingleItem().  The issue is fixed in the Sitecore CMS 6.3.0 rev.100716 release. See [Release Notes](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog.aspx).  Since we are using 6.2, I had to rewrite my method to use a Sitecore Query instead of the Fast Query.

Comment: Appears that this is now an issue in 6.5.0 (rev. 121009) but for Sitecore query (but at position 5).  Joy.

Comment: This is also an issue in Sitecore 6.6, so if the bug was fixed, it was re-introduced.

Comment: We are using 8.1 update 2 and also encountering this. If the query is prefixed with "fast:" or "query:", it simply does not work.

Comment: Still an issue on Sitecore 9.2

Answer (score 18):

When using Sitecore Query, you need to escape item names with dashes. From [SDN](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Using%20Sitecore%20Query/Sitecore%20Query%20Syntax.aspx):

> Items with dashes in names (“-”) should be included in “#” symbols. Please use such syntax: /sitecore/content/Home/#About-us#. Otherwise you may get the following error: Invalid lookup source "/sitecore/content/TestSiteB/Home/About-us": End of string expected at position 38. Also, an item name should be included in “#” symbols if it contains “and” or “or” word and is used before “//*” symbols. For example: "/sitecore/content/Home/#news and events#//*".

UPDATE:
I have confirmed that this applies to Fast Query as well.

```
End of string expected at position 27. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Sitecore.Data.Query.ParseException: End of string expected at position 27.

Source Error: 


Line 21:         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 22:         {
Line 23:             Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectSingleItem("fast:/sitecore/Content/Home/Test-Item");
Line 24: 
Line 25:             Model = Sitecore.Context.Item;
```

The same code runs fine with #escapes#:

```cs
Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectSingleItem("fast:/sitecore/Content/Home/#Test-Item#");
```

Comment: I'm using Sitecore Fast Query, not Sitecore Query. The dashes are not the problem.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you tried escaping them? My instinct would be that Fast Query would utilize the same parsing logic, making the dashes a requirement.

Comment: I'm positive it's not the dashes. My error is at position 4 and there is not a dash any where around it. I used another solution. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your solution here then for the next person who has an issue such as this?

Comment: @techphoria414 Saved my bacon today with this while using SPE.

Comment: And how is one supposed to do this if they are simply injecting a path via `Item.Paths.Path`? Does this expect me to find every item name in the path with dashes, ands or ors and manipulate the string before using it?

Comment: To answer my own question above - one can simply replace all dashes in the path with dashes surrounded by hashes (#) like: `item.Paths.Path.Replace("-", "#-#")`.