# Sitecore Fast Query - How to search for text containing special characters (such as an apostrophe)?

Tags: c#, .net, escaping, sitecore

Perhaps I'm blind but I can't find any documentation on escaping special characters for Sitecore's fast query.

For example, I want to search content items that contain the following text in their description: "hot n' tasty"

Note: I've tried the following escaping:

```
var searchTerm = "hot n'' tasty";  // thought it might need to be escaped for sql
var searchTerm = "#hot n' tasty#"; // this is how you do some other sitecore escaping
var searchTerm = "hot n\' tasty";
```

Sample application code:

```
var searchTerm = "hot n' tasty";
var query = string.Format("fast:/sitecore/content/Home/Products//*[@ContentDescriptionText='%{0}%']", searchTerm);
var items = Database.SelectItems(query);
```

Currently, this is giving me an exception so I'm assuming I need to do some sort of escaping:

> "]" expected at position 67.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Sitecore.Data.Query.ParseException: "]" expected at
>   position 67.

Comment: Do you have to "search" through alot of items using this fast query, or is it just an example of something going wrong!?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here is a post](http://newguid.net/sitecore/2012/escape-characterswords-in-a-sitecore-query/) doing exactly what you are trying to do.  Basically you have to use an escaped double quote to wrap the field value that contains a quote.

```
var searchTerm = "hot n' tasty";
var query = string.Format("fast:/sitecore/content/Home/Products//*[@ContentDescriptionText=\"%{0}%\"]", searchTerm);
var items = Database.SelectItems(query);
```

EDIT: Added link CoolMcGrr references on escaping fast queries and it's limitations.. [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query001.pdf)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link and the response.  That appears to have gotten me steered in the right direction.  That article is largely unintelligible and the answer you provide (based on the said unintelligible article) is slightly off.  We don't need to add <strong> html elements to string but rather use escaped double quotes in the string rather than apostrophes around the variable data.  I'll post an update that works.

Comment: Yeah I almost edited it with \" but since I couldn't test it I didn't... I've edited my answer so it won't be confusing to someone else looking for the same thing...  glad I could steer you in the right direction!

Comment: Oops, missed it at first.  Thanks for updating your answer and I've marked it as correct!

Comment: Also worth looking at http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query001.pdf for info on escaping fast queries and its limitations

Comment: @CoolMcGrrr Thanks... added the link to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @Kevin's answer and link, I was able to come up with a suitable solution:

```
var searchTerm = "hot n' tasty";
// old code for comparison
//var query = string.Format("fast:/sitecore/content/Home/Products//*[@ContentDescriptionText='%{0}%']", searchTerm);
var query = string.Format("fast:/sitecore/content/Home/Products//*[@ContentDescriptionText=\"%{0}%\"]", searchTerm);
var items = Database.SelectItems(query);
```