# Sitecore Fast Query Not Returning Items

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am having a problem where an item that exists in the content tree is not being retrieved by Sitecore fast query. The version of Sitecore is 6.5 (rev 121009). The odd thing is that this works in another environment. I have tried cleaning the databases by following the steps outlined [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jonelrienton/archive/2012/06/29/sitecore-fast-query-not-returning-items-when-searching-for-item-names-issue-and-how-to-fix.aspx) but still the query is failing. The item I am trying to retrieve is the email test02072013:

[image]

The fast query being used is:

fast:/sitecore/content/Home/Email Campaign/Test 02072013/Sent//*[@@templatename='HTML Message']

I have checked that the template is correct and the path to the item exists. I have tried running the query in the xpath builder but still no luck. Additionally a normal sitecore query doesn't work either: 
[image]

Am I missing something obvious or does anyone have another approach I can try? 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try to run like :

```
 fast:/sitecore/Content/Home/#Email Campaign#/#Test 0207#/Sent//*[@@templateName='Html Message']
```

It was a bug with spaces on item names but I know it was fixed on some version .

Are you running on: Sitecore Query Notation?

Comment: yes now the query succeeds, do you know what version the fix was applied?

Comment: I don't know exactly what version it was fixed, but on this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205288/sitecore-fast-query-gives-parse-exception they wrote : Sitecore CMS 6.3.0 rev.100716 release

Comment: Thanks, it seems its also an issue with 6.5 (rev 121009)