# Sitecore Item Web Api with a Dash or Hyphen on its path

Tags: sitecore

Does anybody know how to escape hyphens / dashes when using the sitecore item web api?

Path: sitecore/content/Site/Home/Test-page/*

This is my request:

```
host/-/item/v1/?sc_database=web&query=%2fsitecore%2fcontent%2fSite%2fHome%2fTest-page%2f*
```

This is the response:

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":{"message":"Bad Sitecore query (/sitecore/content/Site/Home/Test-page/*)."}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to wrap anything with a space or a hyphen with the # character. e.g:

```
Path: sitecore/content/Site/Home/#Test-page#/*
```

Thanks to the comment below, hash tags will need to be encoded. That means your url would look like this:

```
Path: host/-/item/v1/?query=/sitecore/content/Site/Home/%23Test-page%23/*
```

Check out [Sitecore Fast Query Gives Parse Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205288/sitecore-fast-query-gives-parse-exception)

Comment: Thanks, it works. The only thing, I replaced # by its encoded code %23 sitecore/content/Site/Home/%23Test-page%23/*

Comment: note that this also works with Sitecore Powershell Extensions when doing a Get-Item call with a query path, like this: `Get-Item -Path master: -Query "/sitecore/content/Home/#some-path-with-hyphens#//*[@@templatename='Folder']"`